# Redirect url to html file with appended parameter

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I asked this question on serverfault.com, but I did not get full answer.

I need to redirect requested url to a html file on the file system. I already know the answer to this:

```
location /this/is/some/url {
    index file.html;
    alias /path/to/the/;
}
```

The location of file.html on the file system is /path/to/the/file.html.

However, I also need to append an empty parameter to the end of the url `/this/is/some/url`. So it should look like this `/this/is/some/url?_escaped_fragment_=`.

I tried various examples with rewrite but it did not help because I don't use correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a redirect unless the parameter is present. Because it is an empty parameter, it may be simplest to use a regular expression on `$request_uri`.

```
location /this/is/some/url {
    index file.html;
    alias /path/to/the;

    if ($request_uri !~ [?].*\b_escaped_fragment_=) {
        return 302 $uri?_escaped_fragment_=&$args; 
    }
}
```

The example above assumes that there may be other parameters present, hence the trailing `&`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I don't need any additional parameters will it be safe to remove this part `&$args`?

Comment: Yes, definitely - I only added it for completeness.